# CakePHP Pagination Order Result

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, pagination

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [Host] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2821
                    [user_id] => 7090
              ) 
            [Review] => Array
                (
                      [0] => Array
                          (
                                 [id] => 852
                                 [host_id] => 2821
                                 [user_id] => 6592
                           ) 
                      [1] => Array
                          (
                                 [id] => 853
                                 [host_id] => 2821
                                 [user_id] => 6532
                           ) 
         )
[1] => Array
        (
            [Host] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2221
                    [user_id] => 7390
              ) 
            [Review] => Array
                (
                ) 
         )
```

I want to show order of pagination result on basis of count review of host.I am trying to use concept of virtual fields to sort.

Please help me to suggest this ..

Comment: "I am trying to use concept of virtual fields to sort.", so what have you tried?

Comment: I am using to add virtual field in Review Model .....   var $virtualFields = array(
    'rw_count' => 'COUNT(Review.host_id)'
);

Comment: and what have you tried in order to accomplish the sort? (that's what I meant previously, sorry I was unclear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [Cakephp websie](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#limitations-of-virtualfields)

> The implementation of virtualFields has a few limitations.  First you
>   cannot use virtualFields on associated models for conditions, order,
>   or fields arrays.

However workaround is something along the lines with:

**Review Model:**

```
public $virtualFields = array('rw_count' => COUNT(Review.host_id));
```

**Host Model:**

```
class Host extends Model{
    public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
        parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
        $this->virtualFields['rw_count'] = $this->Review->virtualFields['rw_count'];
    }
}
```

**Hosts Controller**

```
public $paginate = array(
    'limit' => 25,
    'order' => array(
        'rw_count' => 'desc'
    )
);
```

Given that I don't have full details of your schema, this is what I presume what you could use but the concepts remain the same